# How to add hidden commits?

Tags: git

I have project with a lot of commits. I would like to add something to this project, but I don't want to have new commits in history, but instead of, I would like to have it with last date.

I know that I can use `git rebase`, but it allows create one commit only with first date.

My example:

- First commit (other_author, on master) - 2019-06-23 10:00:00
- Second commit (other_author, on master) - 2019-06-23 11:00:00
- Third commit (other_author, on master) - 2019-06-23 12:00:00

Now I would like to start my work. I add two new commits:

- Fourth commit (me, on develop) - 2019-06-23 14:00:00
- Fifth commit (me, on develop) - 2019-06-23 15:00:00

And I push this into repository. Next day I would like to add the next commit:

- Sixth commit (me, on develop) - 2019-06-24 10:00:00

And now... What should I do to have that history on master:

- First commit (other_author, on master) - 2019-06-23 10:00:00
- Second commit (other_author, on master) - 2019-06-23 11:00:00
- Third commit (other_author, on master) - 2019-06-23 12:00:00
- Last commit (me, on master) - 2019-06-24 10:00:00 (contains fourth, fifth, and sixth commits from develop)

Exact hours are irrelevant. I just want to hide dates from previous commits and have only one commit with the last date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge --squash` to get only one commit from all of them, but it will be a new commit though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--amend` to your commit command to commit and change the message of the last commit, without adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could amend the commit every time, and push it when it's ready.

e.g.

```
 git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: This will keep the timestamp and message of the original commit

Answer (score 0):

If you already pushed to the remote repo, then your best bet would be to use the squash suggestion above, when you merge to master. This will give you one commit on master.

You don't want to change the history in the remote repo after pushing to it. It's such a bad idea I won't even mention how to do that.

If you have not pushed to the remote repo, then the suggestions above using --amend are a good idea.